# Java Abstract Class with two nearly identical methods

Tags: java, methods, abstract-class

I have created an Abstract class and am now combining the code from two different classes into it. Both the codes are similar, but with one line difference. How do I create the Abstract method with the similar portions, but differentiate for the one class that has an extra line of code?

For example:

```
public void exampleOneMethod(int number) {
  ***userChoice = choice - 2;***
  while (userChoice.getNumber(number) == 0) {
     number--
  }
  option = false;
}

public void exampleTwoMethod(int number) {
  while (userChoice.getNumber(number) == 0) {
    number--
  }
  option = false;
}

public void abstractMethod(int number) {
  while (userChoice.getNumber(number) == 0) {
    number--
  }
  option = false;
}
```

How do I put userChoice = choice - 2; into the abstract class only when example1 is extending the abstract class?

Comment: You don't.  Instead, redesign your class hierarchy so that example1 gets the correct behavior without resorting to a hack.  You might also want to use interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about try using `interface` instead?

```
public interface newInterface {
    default void exampleTwoMethod(int number) {
        while (userChoice.getNumber(number) == 0) {
            number--
        }
        option = false;
    }

    default void exampleOneMethod(int number) {
        userChoice = choice - 2;
        while (userChoice.getNumber(number) == 0) {
            number--
        }
        option = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When you want to **implement** this interface:

for example one:

```
public class exampleOneClass implements newInterface {
     public void exampleOneMethod(int number) {
         newInterface.super.exampleOneMethod(number)
     }
}
```

for example two:

```
public class exampleTwoClass implements newInterface {
    public void exampleTwoMethod(int number) {
        newInterface.super.exampleTwoMethod(number)
    }
}
```

It is a bit awkward to do this, as Tim suggested in the comment, you may need to consider rebuilding your class hierarchy.

For more information about **default** method in Java, please refer to this link.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: This would be my the best answer if I was told not to use Interfaces for this program. It helped me find a solution outside of what I was asking though. Just left that method out of the abstract class and used getters for the variables I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to extend it into two separate further classes, one with, the other without.  `extend` is only for sharing common code, if it is not common code then it is not an implementation fit for inheritance, which is why [composition is generally favored over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Either put the additional manipulation into an abstract method and do it there, extending the class twice and leaving the method empty in one or just having `exampleOneMethod` implemented by two separate extending classes.  Alternatively, redesign to make it fit for inheritance or redesign to make it use composition.